# Create a trigger that removes a name from a table if it is present in another

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

To futher clarify i was trying to create a `trigger` that checks a table for a number in sql.

If it finds said number then it erases that entire row.

It uses a separate table of names to check.

I thought it be could done using a `join` but have had no luck.

So it would look like this I suppose `if(tb1.name = tb2.name) then DELETE row`.

I'm sorry if the formatting is off.

EDIT; I am using phpmyadmin so some of the the code may be missing but here is the code from my latest "attempt" 
It uses on INSERT and time is set to AFTER
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM no fly list WHERE PassengerId.Id = Passenger.Id)
have not added the DELETE as of now but the work is somewhat ongoing

Comment: Can you post some code that [you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Wait so does it check the table name for a number or a row in the table for a number?

Comment: It checks for a number. I have several tables but 1 for passengers and 1 for flights and another for DoNotFly(DNF). I have the passengers ID as a number and i have that number in flights as i have that same number in DNF  but only for a select few. What im trying to do with this trigger is remove the passenger only from flights if it is also in DNF. So it would remove him from that flight but not the passengers table or the DNF table

Comment: On what table exactly are you planing to create a trigger and on what event (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)?

Comment: I have it on INSERT so if a DNF name is added on the flights table it is erased. Not sure if this answers your question but im fairly new to sql. EDIT: Also i have time set to AFTER not sure if this helps

Comment: Can you post DDL (create table statements) for your tables?

Comment: BTW What database are you using? In your tags you have both mysql and sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `flight` and `dnf` both have `passenger_id` column that uniquely identifies a passenger of interest then your trigger might look like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER dnf_insert AFTER INSERT 
ON dnf
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM flights WHERE passenger_id = NEW.passenger_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

*If you post DDL (create table statements) for all relevant tables we can refine the query*

Comment: @Viedt Dit it help? Do you need more help with your question?